# Need to ignore some Directories using node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, nodes

Is this even possible to ignore few sub-directories and read rest of the sub-directories present inside main directories

like:

```
Main Directory
-sub-directory1
-sub-directory2
-ABC Folder
-PQR Folder
-sub-directory3

output: 
[sub-directory1
sub-directory2
PQR]

ignore:
[ABC
sub-directory3]
```

Code I have which read all the directories and file and i want to distinguish some directories

```
const fs = require("fs");
const path = require("path");

async function getFile(folderPath) {
  let files = await fs.readdir(folderPath);
  files = await Promise.all(
    files.map(async (file) => {
      const filePath = path.join(folderPath, file);
      const stats = await fs.stat(filePath);
      if (stats.isDirectory()) {
        return getFile(filePath);
      } else if (stats.isFile()) return filePath;
    })
  );

  return files.reduce((all, folderContents) => all.concat(folderContents), []);
}
```

please help

Comment: Where you're doing if (stats.isDirectory()), can't you just add another condition there to make sure it's not of the sub-directories to exclude?

Comment: Please provide a better example and problems that you faced with your own solution so that question can be answered correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote the function `getFilesSync` first argument is directory which you want to get, the second argument is array - list of folders names to ignore.

```
const fs = require("fs");

function getFilesSync(fPath, ignore, response) {
  if (!response) { response = []; }
  if (!ignore) { ignore = []; }

  var files = fs.readdirSync(__dirname+fPath);
  for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
    if (fs.statSync(__dirname+fPath+"/"+files[i]).isDirectory()) {
      var ign = false;
      for (var j = 0; j < ignore.length; j++) {
        if (ignore[j] == files[i]) {
          ign = true;
          break;
        }
      }
      if (!ign) {
        response.concat(getFilesSync(fPath+"/"+files[i], ignore, response));
      }
    } else {
      response.push(fPath+"/"+files[i]);
    }
  }
  return response;
}

console.log( getFilesSync("/test", ["test1", "test2"]) );
```

Comment: hi @Fakt309 its showing me this error `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: SyntaxError: Illegal continue statement: no surrounding iteration statementat addDocument`

Comment: i tried your code but still not working i cant ignore directories which i want to ignore 
but Thank You

Comment: Take a look i created new function it is work on my server nodejs. first argument is directory which you want to get, the second argument is array - list of folders names to ignore.

Comment: fs.readdirSync is not a function @Fakt309

Comment: if you have this error you should try `npm install browserify-fs` then insert code `var fs = require('browserify-fs');` instead of `const fs = require("fs");`

Comment: self is not defined  @Fakt309

Comment: did you delete `const fs = require("fs");` ?

Comment: you should install browserify-fs by write in cmd ctroke `npm install browserify-fs` then replace string in code above `const fs = require("fs");` to `var fs = require('browserify-fs');`

Comment: How do you start your nodejs server? `node index.js` right?

Comment: Also you can try `npm i`or download new version node js https://nodejs.org/en/download/

Comment: i start my node by npm run local